# accessing web service

Tags: java, web-services

I have created and registered a web service. Now I wish to make a simple web app to access the web service. I used axis2 for the web service server. the client is provided with the data to be processed by the web service in the form of xml format file (data.xml). My jsp form has a textbox (to provide the location of the data.xml) and an "invoke" button that will access call the web service. I assume the jsp will first send the request to servlet and then the servlet will be the one responsible to call the web service.
the web service is hosted in PC1, the web app that contains JSP accessing the web service is in PC2, and the data.xml is in PC3. So the user will be working from PC3, open web browser in PC3 to access jsp in PC2 which will then invoke the web service in PC1.

1. What's the syntax to call web service from servlet? I wonder if the axis2 is usable in the client side.
2. how do I construct the SOAP request (I assume the SOAP request is constructed in the servlet)? hopefully I don't need to construct the SOAP request string by string.
3. regarding data.xml, I assume jsp will upload the file to servlet, so the servlet will receive a file as parameter. Is this the correct way?
   thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Axis2, generate the client proxy with it (wsdl2java is your best friend) and will create a standard java proxy for your web service. There's no need to get hands dirty creating the SOAP envelope manually... (at least in 99% of the scenarios).

Just produce a WSDL (writing it or generating it with java2wsdl) then use it to produce a java proxy for calling your Web Service.

Regarding how to use the proxy...

IMHO direct call from jsp is a no-no. Better have the JSP collect data and POST them to a servlet, then perform WebService call within the servlet, manage response (which will be a pure java object if you use the Axis2 framework), handle errors and then forward to another JSP giving the results.

JSP are somewhat easy to write, but in the long run, better use them for what they were planned and keep business logic within servlets

Here two ant tasks for doing WSDL and Client Generation.

```
<!-- create the wsdl file -->
<target name="genwsdl">
    <echo message="Generate the WSDL file"/>
    <taskdef name="java2wsdl" classname="org.apache.ws.java2wsdl.Java2WSDLTask" classpathref="axis2.classpath"/>
    <java2wsdl className="org.stackoverflow.YourWebServiceClassName"
               servicename="YourServiceName"
               description="Whatever..."
               outputLocation="./wsdl"
               locationuri="http://localhost:8081/NameMe/CoolService">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${axis2.classpath}"/>
                <pathelement location="./build/classes"/>
            </classpath>
    </java2wsdl>
    <echo message="Generation of the WSDL file complete"/>
</target>


<target name="genclient" depends="genwsdl">
    <taskdef name="axis2-wsdl2java" classname="org.apache.axis2.tool.ant.AntCodegenTask" classpathref="axis2.classpath"/>
    <axis2-wsdl2java wsdlfilename="./wsdl/YourWsdl.wsdl" output="./client overwrite="true"/>
</target>
```

Once you've generated your client classes (Proxy), you can use them to call the web service.

It will be something like:

```
YourServiceStub stub = new YourServiceStub(wsEndPointUrl);
```

then in the stub you'll have a method for each remote published method and static classes for wrapped requests/responses objects. But at this point a little reading of Axis2 client docs is mandatory.

Comment: yes, so basically jsp will upload the file to the servlet located in PC2. Could you give me the syntax to construct the SOAP message from the servlet and invoking the web service in te servlet? thanks

Comment: It's a little hard, I can add an example of an ant task doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to do it by hand you should use a webservice stack. Apache CXF and Metro are good candidates.

That said, I have no clue what do you want to do with that data.xml of yours.

1. Depends on the framework
2. You don't. That's what the framework is for.
3. If you want multipart support, you should take a look around for ready-made servlets. Or better yet, use Spring framework :)